# Samba, other non interactive accounts - noshell, nologin, or blank?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, solaris, samba

Conducting a user account cleanup accross Solaris and Redhat linux systems, many of which have a number of Samba shares.

What preference do people have for creating the local unix accounts for non interactive Samba users? In particular, the shell entry:

1. noshell
2. nologin
3. blank

And why?

JB

Answer (score 2):

I have seen the shell set to the `passwd` command so that logging in only gives an opportunity to change the password.    This may or may not be appropriate in your non-interactive user case, but it has the upside of allowing people to change passwords without bothering an admin.

Answer (score 1):

I've always thought /bin/false was the standard.  Some ISPs use a little menu system that lets them change their password / contact / finger info, check usages, etc. Whatever you use, you may want to add it to your /etc/shells file as well if you want the user to be able to use FTP for instance, as some services will be denied to users who are not using a shell listed in that file.

Comment: I had forgotten about /usr/bin/false, thanks to your answer I did some googling. This blog post has some good information on why NOT to use /usr/bin/false:

http://www.semicomplete.com/articles/ssh-security/

As I want samba account access, perhaps this is not so much an issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I usualy send all mine to /dev/null that way I don't ever have to worry about it.
I have known some people who set it to /bin/logout so that when someone logged in they were logged back out.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do blank. That runs /bin/sh.